# How to importing data from a .dbf file into a mongodb collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dbf, dbase

So for my internship project i have to create a webservice where i import data from a dbf file (loaded automatically from a immutable location on the client's POS), to a mongodb collection, and display every element from that collection on a web page, where the client can modify its contents.

So far i have tried to read the dbf file and turn it into a json file to then import its objects to that , but it is taking me a lot of time and resources to do so, and the last part of that attempt has failed so far; plus the code is getting a bit out of control when it comes to readilibity (first project!). Does anyone know how to import and display that dbf file in a more efficient way? If so, could you please describe it as clearly as you can?

Also, forgive me if the text is too long or complex, or if i was not clear enough  to understand my issue. Feedback is appreciated, since this is my first question here!

Comment: What is taking a lot of time & resources? Dumping the dbf into JSON? Loading the JSON into MongoDB? What is that "last part" that failed? What language do you use? Have you discussed this issue with your co-workers?

Comment: Hi Kevin! Both dumping the file into json, and then importing that JSON into MongoDB are taking a lot of time and resources; worst, every change on any product must be recorded and saved on the original dbf file!  That "last part" that failed was importing the objects into a MongoDB collection, so i could manipulate them later. My webservice is based on the MEAN architecture, but so far i do not have any AngularJS code in use... I did talk with my co-workers about this, but they never EVER worked on a project like this one, with such an antique format. They told me about OLEDB, though...